# A plane not visible in Viewport appears in render

Tags: rendering

I have a problem, some plane appears in the middle of scene and it looks like that everything is drowning, no object is hidden. I tried to delete models one by one and hit render if some object was weird, but no luck.

Does someone have any idea what could I try, or should I start from the begining and import all models[image]

Comment: 0

Do you have any modifiers on objects that could be set to not show in viewport but show in render?

Comment: only Array modifier on a part of the roof, other than that, nothing, do not know what to do....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

First press the button marked red, then enable the option in marked yellow. It should make the plane appear in the viewport and you can remove it. Don't ask me why it's not enabled by default. This is the method to hide objects in [3d View](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/index.html) but not for the actual rendering. It's meant to work across linked copies in different scenes or separate files.

Also see: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/outliner.html#restriction-columns

Comment: I just realized that this was the ultimate solution. It turns out that plane model was hidden, do not have any idea how this happened, thank you very much....